# Unity 5.3.1f1 crashing every time while opening in windows 10

Tags: unity-game-engine

freshly installed Unity 5.3.1f1

When tried to open unity it is crashing --

Tried with Run as administrator

Also followed instructions from 
[answers.unity3d.com](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/888003/getting-unity-to-work-on-windows-10.html)
 but nothing helped

I have added same question on answers.unity3d community -- But not got satisfying response. [my question link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1127101/unity-531f1-crashing-every-time-while-opening-in-w.html) -- You can check error log there

Can somebody help?

I am using `hp pavilion p097tx` laptop with `windows 10` -- Did it make any difference? Any graphical dissimilarity? please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Did Unity run fine on Win10 before the update? Or did you just update to win10?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: 5.3.1f1 had plenty of problems, download [5.3.2](http://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) or [the latest patch releases](http://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases)

Comment: @trojanfoe `but if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!`

Comment: @AntiHeadshot Well I expect that's for questions about using those software tools, not issues with crashing and O/S-related issues.

Comment: @AntiHeadshot When I brought laptop its come with windows 8.1 licensed version. Then with the free update I have updated os to windows 10. And recently I have installed unity on it.

Comment: @NikaKasradze I will install 5.3.2 Today and update you. Thanks

Comment: @NikaKasradze I have tried installing 5.3.2 as well as 5.1.1 -- But no success. The issue is same CRASHING on startup. Did disabling antivirus help?

Comment: never tried, I don't think it would cause a crash.

Comment: @NikaKasradze in the error log there is dll MZA64.dll -- By googling I found that its an Mazaa malware. Also mdnsNSP.dll Bonjour dll I will try to remove these two and will check again. Will update you -- Do you think that might be the problem.

Comment: if you got your installer from unity.com than probably it's the antivirus that's freaking out. try disabling it for a while, restart and install Unity. if it works get rid of that antivirus and get something else.

Comment: @NikaKasradze I have uninstalled MZA64.dll and bonjour and Guess what Unity started successfully. The virus software cause the problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my own problem

The issue was the malware software installed which was causing Unity crash.

I have unistalled `Mekka` as well as `bonjour` software. And restarted system then started unity with `run as administrator` with no issue.

So if `unity` crashesh and you doesn't know the exact cause, Then the issue might be the an `malware dll` or `software` which is present on your system. Check the error log which unity provides which will give you idea about the specific `dll` which is `causing crash`. Then check info about it on internet `That might be an malware` -- Remove that baster Restart system and open Unity.

-- Happy Gaming

Comment: Unity also act as Anti-virus -- ha ha. They need to mention it in documentation.

Comment: Hi,
your answer is 100% correct. I wish i could make 100 up votes. because i updated unity to new version and i was facing this problem . but after uninstall the anti-malware its started working perfect.

Comment: must try this answer if unity is crashing during randomly working on any project and no any sequence of work made. mostly if user is setting layout styles or working on canvas.